# perform mathematical operation on shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

hi i have a wordpress website which provide product price available. my theme set lowest price of product in meta field and i am able to display by short code [wp_custom_meta field="offer_product_price"]
But, now what i have to do is perform math operation on this data i am getting with shortcode and display in post.

i want to provide EMI of the product by performing calculation based on price,interest rate and months.

thanks

Comment: If this is inbuilt short code and doesn't have the functionality you needed, you can write your own short code.

Comment: Yes i want to do the same and want to create shortcode.. I know programming but do not now about much about about wordpress..    if this 30000 is lowest which i can get by shortcode [wp_custom_meta field="offer_product_price"]   now i want to perform some calculation like get EMI of 3 Months, 6 Months, & 12 Months based on interest rates 12%,13% &14% per year..   i can create shortcode can also calculate but how can i access the value of [wp_custom_meta field="offer_product_price"] in php code.. so that calculation should be done on current post..